# Seqeunce of nonnegative $L^2$ functions converging weakly to $0$ whose squares converge to $1$ in weak*?

Tags: limits, weak-convergence

I am trying to construct a sequence $\{ f_n \} \in L^{2}[0,1]$ with $f_{n} \geq 0$ a.e. such that $\int f_n g dx \to 0$ for each $g \in L^2$ and $\int |f_n|^2 h dx \to \int h dx$ for all $h \in C[0,1]$.

Without assuming nonnegativity this is trivial (e.g. $e^{inx}$).  With nonnegativity, the situation seems more delicate in that if we strengthen the requirement that $\int |f_n|^2 h dx \to \int h dx$ to all $h \in L^1$ then no such sequence exists (in fact as soon as $\int f_{n} dx \to 0$, nonnegativity implies convergence in measure to zero so Egorov's Theorem rules out such a thing).

Comment: Answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454481/sequence-of-l2-functions-converging-to-zero-weakly-s-t-f-n2-converges-t